# Weight on a scale

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, weight, scales

imagine that you're at the baggage weigh in point at an airport. your luggage is on the scale and you try to cheat the price by pivoting your heel on the ground and toe beneath one end of the suitcase to elevate it slightly up and off one end of the scale (so the handler can’t see).

my question being would this actually change the weight and decrease or am i correct in thinking nothing would change

Comment: A mass put on two scales weighs less on each than on one. You are the other scale.

Comment: Convince all passengers to do what you recommend.  That way, when the plane is overweight and crashes on take-off, you will be saving a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

Initially one upward force due to the scale (which is equal to the reading on the scale) would balance the downward force (weight) due to the luggage.

With the toe providing a second upward force to balance the weight the other upward force (reading on the scale) must be smaller.
If the line of action of the vertical upward force due to the toe passes through the centre of mass of the luggage then the reading on the scale would be zero.

Comment: that’s brilliant thanks so much for clarifying for me 